# Can't use SUM in SQL when the value is not integer

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using below SQL in SNOWFLAKE and couldn't able to get the count of the instance. The end goal that i am trying to achieve is that i want to know that count of teams and instances that have the same the same Issue.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    priority,
    QID,
    issue,
    solution,
    team,
    instance,
    COUNT(team) AS TEAM_COUNT,
    SUM(instance) AS Instance_count
FROM  
    ABCDTABLE
WHERE 
    priority != 'NONE'
GROUP_BY
    priority, QID, issue, solution, team, instance
ORDER_BY
    priority, QID, issue, solution, team, instance
```

I get this error:

> Numeric value 'i-21232' is not recognized

Sample data:

```
Priority    QID           Issue                SOLUTION       TEAM    INSTANCE
HIGH        123   Wrong package version     Update Package.   Devops.  i-21232
HIGH        123   wrong package version     update package.   infra.   i-12341
MEDIUM      721.  SSH vulnerability.      Remove old version.  App     i-323232
```

Expected Output:

```
Priority  QID.           Issue              Solution      count(TEAM) COUNT(INSTANCE)
HIGH.     123.   Wrong Package Version.   Update package.       2                2
```

Thank You

Comment: Please do not spam tag RDBMS, tag only the RDBMS you are using!

Comment: You're using `GROUP BY` incorrectly. You should only use `GROUP BY` with "key" (or otherwise meaningful) columns. To "include" data from other columns you need to do a self-`JOIN`.

Comment: MySql <> SQL Server <> Postgres <> SqlLite - please tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using.

Comment: You shouldn't be grouping by the columns you are aggregating.

Comment: Your `Instance` column is not a numeric column. It seems to be a text column (`text`, `varchar`, etc). Values like `i-21232` cannot be used as numbers.

Comment: What is the `SUM` of the `string` values `'i-21232'` and `'i-12341'`? Do you add each character together, treating numerical digits like numbers for something like `'r+33573'`?

Comment: According to your expected output you just want to count the number of instances. Thus, why don't you use `count` instead of `sum`? (You can't apply `sum` to text) Also, do not include `team` and `instance` in the `group by` clause, as you want to count or sum them.

Comment: Not sure why you are using both `count` and `sum`  - it looks like you need `count distinct` each one

Comment: the reason i want to use SUM for the instance is that i want to get the total count of the instances that are having the same issue. If i use count on instance, it doesn't show total count.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to remove the TEAM and INSTANCE columns from the GROUP BY, and change the SUM(INSTANCE) to a COUNT(INSTANCE).

As stated above, you can't SUM data the contains non-numerical values.

E.g. does the below work for you?

```
SELECT 
    priority,
    QID,
    issue,
    solution,
    team,
    instance,
    COUNT(team) AS TEAM_COUNT,
    COUNT(instance) AS Instance_count
FROM  
    ABCDTABLE
WHERE 
    priority != 'NONE'
GROUP BY
    priority, QID, issue, solution
ORDER BY
    priority, QID, issue, solution, team, instance
```

Comment: GROUP BY and ORDER BY should have no underscore.

Comment: @CristiS. you are right - i just copied their code and amended. will edit to reflect correct GROUP and ORDER

Answer (score 1):

So if we take the pasted SQL and data. then fixed the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` and change `SUM(instance)` to `COUNT(instance)`

```
WITH ABCDTABLE(Priority, QID, Issue, SOLUTION,TEAM, INSTANCE) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('HIGH',  123, 'Wrong package version', 'Update Package.', 'Devops.', 'i-21232'),
    ('HIGH',  123, 'wrong package version', 'update package.', 'infra.', 'i-12341'),
    ('MEDIUM',721, 'SSH vulnerability.', 'Remove old version.', 'App', 'i-323232')
)
SELECT 
    priority,
    QID,
    issue,
    solution,
    team,
    instance,
    COUNT(team) AS TEAM_COUNT,
    COUNT(instance) AS Instance_count
FROM  
    ABCDTABLE
WHERE 
    priority != 'NONE'
GROUP BY
    priority, QID, issue, solution, team, instance
ORDER BY
    priority, QID, issue, solution, team, instance
```

we get some perfectly valid SQL, which returns:

| PRIORITY | QID | ISSUE | SOLUTION | TEAM | INSTANCE | TEAM_COUNT | INSTANCE_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HIGH | 123 | Wrong package version | Update Package. | Devops. | i-21232 | 1 | 1 |
| HIGH | 123 | wrong package version | update package. | infra. | i-12341 | 1 | 1 |
| MEDIUM | 721 | SSH vulnerability. | Remove old version. | App | i-323232 | 1 | 1 |

which is not what you want.

So like everybody else, removing `TEAM` & `INSTANCE` from the selection and groupings would give better results.

But you input data is clearly inconsistent. so to lowering will improve that, but then our group by should be swapped to the output column references `1,2,3,4`

```
WITH ABCDTABLE(Priority, QID, Issue, SOLUTION,TEAM, INSTANCE) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('HIGH',  123, 'Wrong package version', 'Update Package.', 'Devops.', 'i-21232'),
    ('HIGH',  123, 'wrong package version', 'Update Package.', 'infra.', 'i-12341'),
    ('MEDIUM',721, 'SSH vulnerability.', 'Remove old version.', 'App', 'i-323232')
)
SELECT 
    lower(priority) as priority,
    QID,
    lower(issue) as issue,
    lower(solution) as solution,
    COUNT(team) AS TEAM_COUNT,
    COUNT(instance) AS Instance_count
FROM  ABCDTABLE
WHERE priority != 'NONE'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

giving:

| PRIORITY | QID | ISSUE | SOLUTION | TEAM_COUNT | INSTANCE_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| high | 123 | wrong package version | update package. | 2 | 2 |
| medium | 721 | ssh vulnerability. | remove old version. | 1 | 1 |

And then as Chris notes, this has the row with a count of one. So you ether made a typo in your example data.

which can be achieved by adding a `HAVING TEAM_COUNT > 1` after the GROUP BY clause. You can reuse a already named output value like I have, or count all rows like Chris notes with `count(*)`

Then there is one point you make in a comment:

> the reason i want to use SUM for the instance is that i want to get the total count of the instances that are having the same issue. If i use count on instance, it doesn't show total count.

I translate that into you want the distinct count, which if we boost the data to:

```
SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('HIGH',  123, 'Wrong package version', 'Update Package.', 'Devops.', 'i-21232'),
    ('HIGH',  123, 'wrong package version', 'update package.', 'infra.', 'i-12341'),
    ('HIGH',  123, 'wrong package version', 'update package.', 'other', 'i-12341'),
    ('MEDIUM',721, 'SSH vulnerability.', 'Remove old version.', 'App', 'i-323232')
```

I read that as your want 2, not 3, thus `COUNT(DISTINCT(instance))` can be used.

```
WITH ABCDTABLE(Priority, QID, Issue, SOLUTION,TEAM, INSTANCE) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('HIGH',  123, 'Wrong package version', 'Update Package.', 'Devops.', 'i-21232'),
    ('HIGH',  123, 'wrong package version', 'update package.', 'infra.', 'i-12341'),
    ('HIGH',  123, 'wrong package version', 'update package.', 'other', 'i-12341'),
    ('MEDIUM',721, 'SSH vulnerability.', 'Remove old version.', 'App', 'i-323232')
)
SELECT 
    lower(priority) as priority,
    QID,
    lower(issue) as issue,
    lower(solution) as solution,
    COUNT(team) AS TEAM_COUNT,
    COUNT(distinct instance) AS Instance_count
FROM  ABCDTABLE
WHERE priority != 'NONE'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
HAVING TEAM_COUNT > 1
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

gives:

| PRIORITY | QID | ISSUE | SOLUTION | TEAM_COUNT | INSTANCE_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| high | 123 | wrong package version | update package. | 3 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

This query will give the desired result

```
SELECT 
    priority,
    QID,
    issue,
    solution,
    COUNT(team) AS TEAM_COUNT,
    COUNT(instance) AS Instance_count
FROM  
    ABCDTABLE
WHERE 
    priority != 'NONE'
GROUP_BY
    priority, QID, issue, solution
ORDER_BY
    priority, QID, issue, solution
```

Comment: GROUP BY and ORDER BY should have no underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following problems:

1. INSTANCE contains non-numeric values, so you cannot use it with SUM. It should be COUNT as well.
2. You can either use a field as it is, or with an aggregate in the SELECT projection. Never both. So you cannot have both team and COUNT(team), or instance and COUNT(instance), in the SELECT clause. Remove team and instance, if you use COUNT(team) and COUNT(instance).
3. Remove from GROUP BY fields you used as aggregates in SELECT. I mean team and instance.
4. If you used aggregates in SELECT, your ORDER BY clause can use the same aggregates, not the fields alone. For instance, you can sort by COUNT(team) or COUNT(instance), not by team or instance.
5. (later edit) It should be also GROUP BY and ORDER BY, with no underscore.
6. (later edit) Your grouping must use a case insensitive issue and solution fields.
7. (later edit) Added HAVING count(*) > 1, because you want groups with at least two rows.

Here is a possible correct version of your query:

```
SELECT 
    priority,
    QID,
    lower(issue),
    lower(solution),
    COUNT(team) AS TEAM_COUNT,
    COUNT(instance) AS Instance_count
FROM  
    ABCDTABLE
WHERE 
    priority != 'NONE'
GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3, 4
HAVING
    count(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    1, 2, 3, 4;
```

**[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qRMunMVYV1wjDsFQFMZmGg/1)**

Comment: it doesn't work becoz i am running this query on snowflake and it throws error  "SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 4 'ABCDTABLE' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.     But if i provide the team and instance in the both  GROP_BY & ORDER_BY then it runs without any errors but it doesn't give desire result.

Comment: It should be also GROUP BY and ORDER BY. No underscore!

Comment: Even without the "underscore", it is the same issue. looks like snowflake is not supporting it.

Comment: Check the new db-fiddle I created (it's for MySQL, but it also works in Snowflake, I checked) and my later-edits.

Comment: @learningfun would you get a look at what I posted, and eventually vote on this? Or I just wasted my time?